# How to Reply to a Tweet from Stream Using Node Module Twit

Tags: node.js, api, twitter

I try to answer tweets that I get from a stream. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44669859/replying-to-a-tweet-using-twit-and-node-js) article, but somehow it doesn't work for me. The tweet is posted, but not as a reply, and in the JSON I get back is in_reply_to_status_id: null

Here's my code:

```
stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
  if ((tweet.text.includes("Oh") || tweet.text.includes("oh") || tweet.text.includes("O") || tweet.text.includes("o")) && (tweet.text.includes("gott") || tweet.text.includes("Gott"))){
    // console.log(tweet)

    const tweetId = tweet.id;

    T.post('statuses/update', { in_reply_to_status_id: tweetId, status: 'Oh Gott' }, (err, data, response) => {
      console.log(data)
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is JavaScript, it is probably mangling the Tweet ID value (read about [Twitter IDs here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/twitter-ids)). You probably need to use

`const tweetId = tweet.id_str`

This will prevent the long integer from being changed by the JavaScript.